# Help me identify a movie with a bar scene and an android

Tags: story-identification, movie, androids

I'm trying to find a movie of which I saw a scene on TV years ago.
The movie looked like it was from the 80s-90s.

Here are all the clues I can give you about it:
On the planet there is no oxygen and it looks sort of like a desert. People go around carrying oxygen tubes and nasal cannulae.

There is this one scene when we see one of the main characters walking into a bar. The bar is pressurized and has oxygen, so people don't need anything to breath in there.

The guy challenges some folks there to a game of pool, and we see him cannon most of the balls in different holes with perfect precision. That's when the others realize that he's a cyborg (or an android or whatever). So they get mad and throw him in a hatch where they take the oxygen away for a minute or so, so he can't breathe.

That's all I recall from the movie.

So, to recap:

- No oxygen in the surface of the planet
- I remember a truck with little plants on it, made to create oxygen
- People go around with oxygen tanks
- There's a bar
- There's a hatch in the bar
- People don't like cyborgs or androids for some reason

Please help! It's been years that I tried to track this movie with no success!
Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Space: Above and Beyond featured an android pool hustler in the episode R&R; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHDBkKhH2Ho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Circuitry Man from 1990. The scene you describe with pool table, bar fight, and the ride in a semi full of plants happens about midway through.

Comment: Dead movie link

Comment: @Valorum youtube video works fine for me.

Comment: @JacobC. - Interesting. Working now

Comment: Thanks so much for this!! I just remembered to check again this thread, 4 years later!!

Comment: @JulianRodriguezOrihuela Please mark this answer as correct!

Comment: Done!! I totally forgot!

Comment: By the way, I just asked ChatGPT the same thing that I asked here and it just responded Total Recall. Our jobs are safe still.